# create lag variable of xts object using $ vs. [] notation

Tags: r, xts, nested-lists

I am trying to create a lagged vector within an xts object using the `lag` function. It works when defining the new vector within the xts object using `$` notation (e.g. `x.ts$r1_lag`), but it does when defining the new variable using square brackets, i.e. `xts[,"r1_lag"]`. See code below:

```
library(xts)
x <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), by='days', length=100),
                runif(1e2), runif(1e2), runif(1e2))
colnames(x) <- c("date", "r1", "r2", "r3")

#the following command works
x.ts <- xts(x, order.by=x$date)
x.ts$r1_lag <- lag(x.ts$r1)
# but the following does not (says subscript is out of bounds)
x.ts <- xts(x, order.by=x$date)
x.ts[,"r1_lag"] <- lag(x.ts[,"r1"])
```

I need to use `[]` notation rather than `$` notation to reference the vectors because if I want to run the lag transformation on vectors in more than one xts object (vectors within a list of multiple xts objects), I can't define the new vectors within the objects using `$` notation, i.e. I cant define the new vectors using the notation in the below stylized loop:

```
for (i in letters) {
  for (j in variables) {
    macro.set.ts$i$paste(j,"_L1",sep="") <- lag(macro.set.ts[[i]][,j])
    macro.set.ts$i$paste(j,"_L2",sep="") <- lag(macro.set.ts[[i]][,j], 2)
    macro.set.ts$i$paste(j,"_L4",sep="") <- lag(macro.set.ts[[i]][,j], 4)
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side note : why do you have a date column in your xts ? you should have only numeric columns and use the date as an index. Otherwise you will not take any profit from using `xts` ( in you example it is just a kind of character matrix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't **need** to use `[<-.xts`. You can use `merge` instead:

```
for (i in letters) {
  for (j in variables) {
    # create all lags
    mst_ij <- macro.set.ts[[i]][,j]
    jL <- merge(lag(mst_ij), lag(mst_ij, 2), lag(mst_ij, 4))
    colnames(jL) <- paste(j, c("L1","L2","L4"), sep="_")
    # merge back with original data
    macro.set.ts[[i]] <- merge(macro.set.ts[[i]], jL)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the merge command is very useful here. It does seem to be some sort of bug, however, that my original method of simply reassigning the xts object with an additional vector works with the `$<-` operator and not with the `[<-` operator as @agstudy mentioned.

Comment: @lrclark: as I commented on agstudy's answer: there is no `$<-.xts`, so `$<-.zoo` is dispatched; and the error with `[<-.xts` is consistent with zoo (i.e. you get the same error if you attempt this with zoo objects instead of xts). I'm not sure if this would be considered a bug in `[<-.zoo`, since this is the same behavior you get with a `matrix` and/or `ts` object (which is what zoo extends).

Answer (score 3):

The error is not related to `lag` function. You get an error because you try assign an xts object with another xts object. This example reproduces the error :

```
x.date= seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), 
                        by = 'days' , length = 5)
x1 <- xts(data.frame(c1=runif(5)), order.by=x.date)
x2 <- xts(data.frame(c2=runif(5)), order.by=x.date)
x1[,'r2'] <- x2

## Error in `[<-.default`(`*tmp*`, , "r2", 
##   subscript out of bounds
```

I find this is coherent within xts logic,  because xts are indexed objects. So it is better here to merge objects or join and conserve the indexed nature of your time series.

```
merge(x1,x2)
```

This will `cbind` the 2 times series and fix any index problem. in fact, `cbind` is just a `merge`:

```
identical(cbind(x1,x2),merge(x1,x2)
```

That's said I think it is a kind of bug that this works for `$<-` operator and not with `[<-` operator.

Comment: Note that there is no `$<-.xts`, therefore `$<-.zoo` is dispatched. And the error with `[<-.xts` is consistent with zoo (i.e. you get the same error if you attempt this with zoo objects instead of xts).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same output with:

```
x.ts <- cbind(x.ts,lag(x.ts[,"r1"]))
```

And

```
x.ts <- transform(x.ts, r1_lag = lag(x.ts[,'r1']))
```

But, be careful with the output. It may look the same but with an altered structure.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
x.ts <- merge(x.ts,lag(x.ts[,"r1"]))
```

You will then probably want to rename the last column that was added:

```
dimnames(x.ts)[[2]][5] <- "r1_lag"
```

This is the result:

```
> head(x.ts)
           date         r1           r2           r3             r1_lag      
2015-01-01 "2015-01-01" "0.23171030" "0.44174424" "0.3396816640" NA          
2015-01-02 "2015-01-02" "0.97292220" "0.74909452" "0.2793033421" "0.23171030"
2015-01-03 "2015-01-03" "0.52320743" "0.49288463" "0.0193637393" "0.97292220"
2015-01-04 "2015-01-04" "0.36574297" "0.69571803" "0.6411834760" "0.52320743"
2015-01-05 "2015-01-05" "0.37563137" "0.13841216" "0.3087215754" "0.36574297"
2015-01-06 "2015-01-06" "0.48089356" "0.32702759" "0.3967609401" "0.37563137"

> class(x.ts)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Hope this helps.